# Verifying the Android Licensing API remotely

Tags: android

I have an application that needs to create a remote account if the user pays for an application using the Android Market.

How might I do this from the application itself in a secure way, ie. I don't want anyone to be able to submit data to a url and create an account, I want this to happen in a verified way. I thought of including an authentication key in the application itself, but that does not stop someone from decompiling the application and taking out the authorisation key.

Is there a way to query the Android Market payments using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it.  You need to write a custom java class based off the original Licensing System, in particular the the verify() method.  You can then run the command using backquotes in php and grab stdout.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api-php/
Don know if this might be of any help.

Comment: This is for the android market only, not android market licensing.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use PHP rather than execute a Java process you may find [this library on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/) verifying Android Market licensing responses useful.

It just takes a few lines of PHP to verify a license and the formatting of keys and OpenSSL stuff is taken care of for you.